# Code First Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I migrated this application and it's database to a production server. In fact within the production environment it runs fine in debug mode... but when I deploy it I get this error. This is a common error with EF Code First but none of the usual fixes have worked. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the "usual fixes" you have tried? Start with your connection string (make sure it works outside VS). Next, what is your database initializer? Also, do you have Automatic Migrations enabled? If yes, turn them off. What we do is turn off the initializer for PROD and use migration scripts to keep it in sync.

Comment: @SteveGreene Performed a Migration then Update-Database. No exceptions during either process but still receiving same error. I've even gone as far as to completely delete the Migrations Directory in my project and the Database in SQL Server and rebuilt it from Code. Amazingly it still is producing the same error.

Comment: Still not clear on what you are trying to do: create a new database in PROD from scratch or move a DEV database to PROD? This is EF6? What initializer are you using?

Comment: I was only doing a migration from one environment (DEV) to another environment(PROD). Normally I just copy the project and the database change the connection string and it runs just fine. In this instance this error is produced when I log in. I am not using an initializer. At first I had data in the existing database... but in trouble shooting I even deleted the database and recreated from scratch with no data... both instances produce the same error. Another note, although I do not think it is related is that this is the second website running on this server... i.e. another MVC app

Comment: Edit your question and show the relevant parts of your context.

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the question but have added the answer as it was a strange circumstance that was difficult to figure out. I think it will rarely happen to others as I have only seen one or two other similar circumstances across the web... but am posting just in case it can help someone else out. I figured it out by deploying a different ASP application to the same application pool which gave a different exception: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.`

After researching this I saw a circumstance where someone suggested giving the IIS USER  the DB Owner role within the corresponding SQL Server Login. I did it as a last ditched effort and amazingly it worked! After doing this I re-deployed the original MVC application that was producing the error above and it worked fine.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.